# Number of Relations

Tags: discrete-mathematics, relations

I was stacked in one question . It was about number of reflexive relations on set with N elements. I know the solution but i don't know the logic behind it . I know we construct nxn matrix and number we find the subset that created by all elements of that matrix except the ones on diagonal. But why do it  so why we exclude diagonal , what is the logic behind of it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The relation $R$ on the set $X$ with $|X| = n$ is a subset of $X \times X$. We can represent this subset by $n \times n$ matrix $A$ which elements are $0$ or $1$, i.e. the pair $(i, j) \in R \subset X \times X$ if and only if $A_{i, j} = 1$.

If $R$ is reflexive, then $A_{i, j} = 1$ for $i = 1, 2, \dots, n$. So the diagonal of it's matrix is fixed. Also we can choose arbitrary values for all other elements. The number of all other elements is $n^2 - n$ which are all the elements of $n \times n$ matrix except $n$ elements on the diagonal.

For each off-diagonal element we have two choices: $0$ and $1$. So the total number of such matrices is $2^{n^2 - n}$.

Comment: What you mean by stating that diagonal is fixed ?

Comment: I mean that you cannot assign arbitrary numbers to the diagonal elements. Since relation is reflexive, they must be equal to $1$ only.

Comment: Then off-diagonal must be set to 0 first  must not be  so?

Comment: The idea is the following. First, you we that if relation is reflexive, then it's matrix has $1$ on the diagonal. Secondly, we prove that if we take arbitrary matrix with $1$ on diagonal and any of $0$ and $1$ off-diagonal, this matrix will represent reflexive relation. So we need to count the matrices with $1$ on diagonal and arbitrary numbers from $\{0, 1\}$ off diagonal.

Comment: ok but i understand that part but how it goes on?  i mean  what is the reason of counting the number of subset of set of elements in off-diagonal elements of matrix?

Comment: There is no such thing as "off-diagonal matrix$ there are off-diagonal elements of the matrix. Could you please ask explain your question in more detail?

Comment: Don't dive too much in details, bratan!